# IIS 8.5 powershell seeing inheritance where no inheritance exists

Tags: .net, powershell, iis, powershell-3.0, iis-8.5

I am trying to modify my IIS Site/Application through PowerShell

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" -Location 'Default Web Site/MySite' -Filter "system.webServer/asp" -Name "enableParentPaths" -Value "True"
```

But when I run this I get the error

```
Get-WebConfiguration : Filename: \\?\C:\inetpub\MySite\web.config
Line number: 9
Error: There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/webServices/jsonSerialization' section defined
```

I realize that the jsonserialization is defined in the "root" for .NET 4.0 sites however this site is using a .NET 2.0 AppPool. I'm able to change this setting just fine with the GUI a number of different ways but as I'm deploying this to a number of servers was hoping to get away from manually defining items and having as much as I can work programmatically.